# Java Gson Incompatible Types

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap, gson

I'm using Gson to encode and decode POJOs to JSON, however, Gson has some unexpected behaviour.

As a matter of fact, I have an object that looks like this

```
public class MyClass{
    public int id;
    public Object someData;
}
```

And it's constructor with `id` and `data`.

I often pass a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` to Object, which Gson is parsing quite perfectly. The problem is the decoding, it decodes it as a hashmap of `Integer,Double` even though I called the function like so:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMapTemplate = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> myData = gson.fromJson(data, hashMapTemplate.getClass());
```

And I then manipulate myData, which throws a

> ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer.

And if I add an explicit cast `(int)` it throws a

> ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer.

What I don't understand is how a HashMap defined to hold two integers can hold wether a Double or a String...

Does anyone have a solution?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to type erasure, the class object for a `HashMap` is the same regardless of whether it's a `HashMap<String, Integer>` or `HashMap<Foo,  Bar>`. In fact, your current code might as well have passed `HashMap.class` to `fromJson` and skipped the template object altogether.

To preserve generic types, you instead need a `TypeToken`:

`HashMap<Integer, Integer> h = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<Integer, Integer>>() {});`

TypeToken uses a clever trick, utilizing `Class.getGenericSuperclass()`,and for that reason it must always be created as a subclass, hence the inline anonymous subclassing syntax.

Comment: How do we deal with this case: using gson.fromJson(JSON, class) but one of the class's properties is Map<Integer, Integer>?

Comment: @JeromeLi That's actually handled automatically. If your class is `class Foo { Map<Integer, Integer> map; }`, then you can deserialize it straight of using `gson.fromJson("{\"map\": {1: 42, 2: 43}}", Foo.class)`. In this case, the type of `Foo` and all its members is known and not affected by type erasure. It's only when the top-level class you're deserializing is generic that you need to use `TypeToken`.